# After image resize new images are partially greyed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resize, imagemagick, blur, rmagick

I am using the following 'rmagick' gem version in my ruby application to process images.

### For image processing

`gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15.4'`

Occasionally (about 1 in 100 times) an image does not resize correctly and the bottom half of it becomes grey (although not the grey I was setting for the background) and also the image becomes blurry sometimes.

Here's my sample code:

```
url_img = open(URI.encode(object.url))
image = Magick::ImageList.new
image.from_blob(url_img.read)
final_image_name = image_name(object, object_type)
img_size = [image[0].columns, image[0].rows]

if img_size[0] > img_size[1]
dimensions = [size[1],(size[1] * img_size[1]/img_size[0])]
else
dimensions = [(size[2]*img_size[0]/img_size[1]),size[2]]
end
resized_image = image.resize(dimensions[0],dimensions[1])
resized_image = resized_image.strip!

watermarked_image = resized_image
watermarked_image.units = Magick::PixelsPerInchResolution
watermarked_image.set_channel_depth(Magick::AllChannels,8)
watermarked_image.density = "72"
watermarked_image.write(temp_file_path)
```

Here's an example of an image greyed out after resizing.

Original Image:

[image: Original Image]

Generated Image:

[image: Generated Image]

Comment: That typically can occur if you run out of /tmp space. Check your /tmp directory to be sure you have enough room. /tmp can collect images that do not get deleted when a system crashes.

Comment: @fmw42 If there is not enough space in /tmp folder, then the operation of generating thumbnail should be broken. I mean there should be an exception.

Comment: Looks like the file stream is ending prematurely, where's the source of the image same fs or is it remote?

Comment: If it runs out of tmp space, then it quits unexpectedly and so I suspect there is no way to issue an error. I am not an expert on such processed, but I have seen that happen when running out of tmp space. Check your IM resources and change your policy.xml file to increase RAM, etc.

Comment: If you are on a shared hosting service, perhaps to many process are going on and you get a time out. As I am not an expert on this, these are just guesses or suggestions to check

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr We are fetching image data from s3 URL. url_img = open(URI.encode(object.url))

Comment: So lets narrow some stuff down also, does this happen to the same image? Does this happen in the same spot on the images?

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr We have scheduled a job which runs over 1000 images. 1 out of 100 images is getting blur or partially greyed out or greyed out with blur. This is happening on a random basis. Additionally, it is running on the multithreaded environment.